# Using fyne widgets with OOP-style

Tags: go, fyne

I want to combine some standard widget in one custom widget. I can do it if put all of widget fields into one container like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

type MyWidget struct {
    widget.BaseWidget

    Cont      *fyne.Container
    text      *widget.Label
    statusBar *widget.Label
    b1        *widget.Button
    b2        *widget.Button

    count uint
}

func (t *MyWidget) Init() {
    t.b1 = widget.NewButton("1", func() {
        t.text.SetText("1")
        t.count++
        t.statusBar.SetText(fmt.Sprint(t.count))
    })
    t.b2 = widget.NewButton("2", func() { t.text.SetText("2") })
    t.statusBar = widget.NewLabel("status")
    bottom := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewCenterLayout(), t.statusBar)
    t.text = widget.NewLabelWithStyle("0", fyne.TextAlignTrailing, fyne.TextStyle{Bold: true})
    t.Cont = fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewBorderLayout(nil, bottom, nil, nil),
        bottom, fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(
            layout.NewGridLayoutWithRows(4),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewCenterLayout(), t.text),
            layout.NewSpacer(),
            fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewGridLayout(2), t.b1, t.b2),
            layout.NewSpacer(),
        ))
}

func Load() *MyWidget {
    obj := &MyWidget{BaseWidget: widget.BaseWidget{}}
    obj.Init()
    return obj
}

func main() {
    f := app.New()
    w := f.NewWindow("")
    obj := Load()
    w.SetContent(obj.Cont)
    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

I used to use GUI toolkits where top widget has opportunity to set container for holding child widgets. Is it possible get solution with Fyne without exported inner container?

Comment: Go is not a traditional OOP language, and OOP design does not tend to be successful in Go.

Comment: @Adrian, Thanks for comment, but you are did not convinced me that OOP 
 in Go doesn't fit for GUI. Fyne samples contain examples with succesful using of OOP-design, and I don't see any reason why there couldn't be right OOP approach for my question.

Comment: That depends very much on what you mean by "OOP". Goes does not have objects, classes, inheritance, or dynamic dispatch. What most OOP developers would consider an "OOP design" is simply not possible in Go, for GUI or anything else.

Comment: @Adrian, I mean encapsulation. I don't like when all GUI elements are putting inside main function because it's really almost impossible to read.
And, btw, Go does have objects, classes(=structs), and embedding instead classic inheritance

Comment: It does not have objects, structs are not classes, and embedding is not inheritance. If you don't want GUI elements in the main function, put them somewhere else; that has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: @Adrian, I really don't want have a debate about terminology. If you know how to solve my issue - provide solution or if I made mistake in formulation of question - fix it. My goal to get an answer and provide opportunity to find and use it for any who stuck with the same question. 

What do you think about - "Using fyne.Containers inside user types?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you look at using a container instead. (I.e. ‘fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(myLayout, widgets...)’.

Widgets and containers are distinct in Fyne. Widgets are an encapsulation for logic, with a renderer to display, Containers are used to group multiple widgets.
There are some widgets that bridge the gap, such as widget.Box and widget.Group, but they typically expose a container, or re-export the container methods.

Generally you don’t make a tree of widgets, but rather a container tree with widgets at the loop.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not an answer on my question. As you can see I already use container in my code. I just not understand how one should grouping widget. Is it OK to do how it's done in my code? Yes or no. 
It's similar to your [calculator](https://github.com/fyne-io/examples/blob/develop/calculator/main.go) sample, but in my case I don't want put window inside my struct. Maybe I just should embed container instead of widget?

Comment: "MyWidget" should not be a widget - all it is doing is holding references to things that the app wants. Calling it "myApp" might be more appropriate - and it should not embed BaseWidget.

There is no reason to hold a reference to "Cont" I don't think, it is returned and set as the content so it could be just returned from a "loadUI" method or such (like Init currently).

Comment: Hm, I should to add more context - I want to do something like very simple wizard dialog (that's nothing other than a sequence of 'pages', each displayed inside a dialog which has the buttons to navigate to the next (and previous) pages). So App should be able set as content some custom page from the set and each page contains some widgets.  MyWidget is just one from such pages.

Comment: So each page should be a `fyne.CanvasObject` and users of the dialog can set whatever content they want. You could use builtin widgets, your own ones or a combination. A container is also a canvas object so you could pass that too. Can you expand on the challenge you are experiencing?

Comment: I have some quiz. Each part - one dialog, in whole it's wizard dialog. User can switch between pages via special buttons. So I provided functions like createPage1, createPage2,... that returns container. I store them as separate variables and set proper one by calling SetContent for window. This way it totally works but only until I need provide dynamic page. In my case if user decided go back - data reload from database and I need update textboxes. I can recreate all widgets but I don't think that it's a good strategy so I need to have one object and way to update his inner state.

Comment: If pages are loaded and then displayed you should not have to re-load just to go back, you could display the same content again if you still have a reference?

Comment: but If you want to implement a full wizard widget to handle more of this for you then you should follow the docs for custom widgets. https://fyne.io/develop/tutorials/write-custom-widget Make sure that your wizard doesn’t know too much about the content, separate paging/navigation from the content/container of each page seems like a best practice.

Comment: No, that's the point, after return back it's new try so I need not only reload page, but also change value of several labels. So contain must be changed.  I can re-create all widgets with new content, but it's just doesn't seems right. 

Yes, thanks, I am aware of custom widget but from my point of view it's strange write custom widget when all I need is have access to widget inside container.

Comment: Sorry I’ve lost track of the problem now, if you want to access items on a container you can. If you would like to fully encapsulate you can make a custom widget that exposes certain apis. Either work and the choice is probably based on how you want to manage your code.

Comment: A QuizWidget could encapsulate the objects, no need to expose inner workings, and have an api like SetQuestion() that would handle the details. Just a thought.

Comment: ok, let's finish on it. I'll use current approach because it simpler than write custom widget which single purpose is to be a wrapper around standart container. But all who read it I strongly recommend do it properly and not as me :P